# Spark Logs in Yarn Resource Manager

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

In YARN Resource Manager fails to open the execution history of the Spark job.

In the Tracking UI column provided Unassigned, when you try to open the history by clicking on job ID falls error:

```
Failed to read the attempts of the application.
```

Through the Spark History Server logs perfectly visible.

```
Failed to read the attempts of the application application_1472109196019_0094.
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1727)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webapp.AppBlock.render(AppBlock.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMAppBlock.render(RMAppBlock.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.render(HtmlBlock.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.renderPartial(HtmlBlock.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.View.render(View.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlPage$Page.subView(HtmlPage.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet.HamletImpl$EImp._v(HamletImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet.Hamlet$TD._(Hamlet.java:845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.TwoColumnLayout.render(TwoColumnLayout.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlPage.render(HtmlPage.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Controller.render(Controller.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RmController.app(RmController.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Dispatcher.service(Dispatcher.java:153)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:900)
    at com.
```

I would be grateful for any ideas!